# How to check moveit version

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am new to ros, I would like to know how can I check moveit version of ROS. I am using ROS noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407746/how-to-check-moveit-version/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

apt show ros-noetic-moveit

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2022-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-10-11**:
this command is giving an error
E: Invalid operation show
I am using ros noetic

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2022-10-11**:
Which Linux distro are you using? Ubuntu?

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-10-11**:
Yes, I am using Ubuntu 20.04

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2022-10-11**:
You se this command apt show ros-noetic-MoveIt